# How to change home_page_header_block identifier?

Tags: header

I have a static block called:  **home_page_header_block**

and in it has a JS code for a slider...

In my **header.html** file;

I have the following code:

```
**

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    <?php if ($homePageHeaderBlock = $this->getChildHtml('home_page_header_block')) : ?>
    <div class="home_page_header_block">
        <?php echo $homePageHeaderBlock ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

**
```

So, I want to duplicate this **home_page_header_block** and change the name of the 2nd one for a 2nd homepage view.

So, for the second block I used the name **home_page_header_block2**

Under the new homepage.html file for header (different header file)
I tried every variation of the code to look for home_page_header_block2 but it shows nothing.  It works fine with the normal header block name.

What do I have to change from that header.html code for it to look for **home_page_header_block2** instead of **home_page_header_block**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me do a primary assumption here. `$this->getChildHtml('home_page_header_block')` is working inside `header.phtml` file. That means you have included the static block as a child block of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`.

Here you are trying to include another block like this.

```
 $this->getChildHtml('home_page_header_block2');
```

From this code what Magento going to understand is, you want to render a child block with name `home_page_header_block2`. So Magento will look for this block in children scope (not global scope. What I mean is, Magento will only consider children block of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` for this search). In this case, such a child block is not defined and hence you are not getting the output.

There are some more points that you need to understand in this context.

1. `$this->getChildHtml('home_page_header_block')` means you want to render the child block content with name `home_page_header_block`. This does not mean it is a static block for sure. It completely depends upon your block definition. If the block with name `home_page_header_block` is a static block, then only it shows your static block content.
2. If you want to include a duplicate of static block `home_page_header_block` in your custom `header.phtml`, then first of all you need to duplicate the static block itself! Means you need to create a new static block with name `home_page_header_block2` and then put the exact content of the `home_page_header_block` static block inside it. This seems absolutely nonsense to me. However I am believing that, you are doing it for a purpose. Secondly you need to include your new static block inside your custom `header.phtml` via layout update. You can do this like this.

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\layout\local.xml`

```
<reference name="[block_name_correpspond_to_header.phtml]">
    <block type="cms/block" name="home_page_header_block2" as="home_page_header_block2">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_page_header_block2</block></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Here `[block_name_correpspond_to_header.phtml]` should be replaced with block name correspond to your custom `header.phtml`

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a lot to think about.  I wasn't aware local.xml had to be referenced.

So the reason I'd like it to have a 2 duplicate home_page_header_block is because each store  (store1, store2) uses different content.   (in this case, different images/different menu/different slider)

Store1 uses home_page_header_block
and I want Store2 to use home_page_header_block2,  the other other option I can see is that I put a code in home_page_header_block that changes the content using if/else codes for different store view

Comment: `local.xml` is not a must requirement. You can use any layout xml update as per your requirement. if your slider and its script are different for different stores, then I recommend you to use `core/template` block instead of static blocks. This will be more easier and maintainable and also your last option would be more easier to implemnt on a `core/template` block. `core/template` block is default block of magento which you can use to define small changes and customizations